# Rails - find_by and where is not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails version - 6.0.3.6

I have one table subscription_attempts and it has one column `attempt_token` which is unique random token for each record and it is generated based on rails's [has_secure_token](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SecureToken/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_token).

I have one method which will try to find record based on attempt_token or id. Below is the method code

```
def random_method(value)
  find_by(id: value) || find_by(attempt_token: value)
end
```

It was working all fine until I got one attempt_token which is starting with a digit. Here is that attempt_token value - `5HqBToVVbFVL4T6TLzuuKju8`

When I use that method it is giving me SubscriptionAttempt record with id 5. I have also tried with where and the result is same.

[image]

When i tried to do this query with where got below exception

```
SubscriptionAttempt.where('id = ?', '5HqBToVVbFVL4T6TLzuuKju8')

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bigint: "5HqBToVVbFVL4T6TLzuuKju8")
LINE 1: ...empts".* FROM "subscription_attempts" WHERE (id = '5HqBToVVb...
```

I am assuming this is not how these methods should behave. It should give a `nil` result if the value is not matching with database value. Can someone please give me the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveRecord automatically does some type casting before querying the database. You can read more about it [here](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/how-rails-works-type-casting). Basically, since ActiveRecord knows that the `id` column is an integer, it will cast the `value` passed to `find_by(id: value)` to an integer and:

```
> '5HqBToVVbFVL4T6TLzuuKju8'.to_i
=> 5
```

Try switching the order:

```
def random_method(value)
  find_by(attempt_token: value) || find_by(id: value)
end
```

This is still not a 100% bullet proof in case you have an instance with an `attempt_token` of `"1234"` and another instance with an id of `1234`. The former will always be returned even if you meant to fetch the latter.

Another solution would be to prepend a constant prefix to your `attempt_token`:

```
ATTEMPT_TOKEN_PREFIX = 'at_'.freeze

def attempt_token_with_prefix
  # provide this value to the user instead of just providing the raw attempt_token
  "#{ATTEMPT_TOKEN_PREFIX}#{attempt_token}"
end

def random_method(value)
  if value.starts_with?(ATTEMPT_TOKEN_PREFIX)
    find_by(attempt_token: value[ATTEMPT_TOKEN_PREFIX.length..])
  else
    find_by(id: value)
  end
end
```

Comment: I have handled it in different way `value =~ /\A\d+\Z/ ? find_by(id: value) : find_by(attempt_token: value)`.